# Complete function space proof

Tags: real-analysis

An exercise in my textbook is as follows.

Let $T>0$ and $L\geq 0$. Consider $C[0, T]$, the space of all continuous real valued funcitons on $[0,T]$, with the metric $\rho$ defined by $$\rho(x, y)=\sup_{0<t\leq T}e^{-Lt}|x(t)-y(t)|.$$ Verify that $(C[0, T], \rho)$ is a complete metric space.

The proof of completeness given in the book goes like this.

Note that $e^{-LT}\leq e^{-Lt}\leq 1$ for $t\in [0, T]$. Therefore, for any $x, y\in C[0, T]$ we have the following inequality: $$e^{-LT}\sup_{0<t\leq T}|x(t)-y(t)|\leq\sup_{0<t\leq T}e^{-Lt}|x(t)-y(t)|\leq \sup_{0<t\leq T}|x(t)-y(t)|$$ This implies that a sequence in convergent in $(C[0,T],\rho)$ if and only if it is convergent in $(C[0,T],d)$ where $d$ is the uniform metric on $[0,T]$. That is, $$d(x, y)=\sup_{0<t\leq T}|x(t)-y(t)|.$$ Therefore, $(C[0, T], \rho)$ is complete since $(C[0, T], d)$ is complete.

My question is from what theorem the completeness of $(C[0, T], \rho)$ and $(C[0, T], d)$ is equivalent? Also from what theorem $(C[0, T], d)$ is complete? Thank you!

Comment: These may not be well-known theorems - simply take a Cauchy sequence, and show that it converges. That said, completeness in the supremum norm should be in any reasonable real analysis book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a space with two equivalent metric $d_1, d_2$. Then $\{a_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d_1$ if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d_2$. From here you can show easily that $(X, d_1)$ is complete if and only if $(X, d_2)$ is.